# Select count from two tables with generate_series

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, question and answer. I would like to select two count(*) from these tables with generates_series month.

```
SELECT to_char(s.tag,'yyyy-mm') AS month
     , count(t.id) AS questions_count
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(min(created_time)::date
                        , current_date::date
                        , interval '1 month'
          )::date AS tag
   FROM   core.questions t
    where t.created_by=2
   ) s
LEFT   JOIN core.questions t ON t.created_time::date = s.tag

GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

I want to get a result from two tables like this

```
month      questions_count   answer_count 
"2006-12" | 4              | 1
"2007-01" | 1              | 2
"2007-02" | 1              | 3
```

Comment: PIVOT/CROSS TAB/conditional aggregation